# Calculating the size of a page table

Tags: page-tables

I have an assignment with the following prompt:

```
The page size for a virtual memory system is 8KB.
The instruction TLB is direct-mapped with 2 sets and each block contains one translation.
^(I don't believe this is relevant for the following 3 questions, as there are two more questions about the TLB)

The number of bits in a virtual address is 20.
The number of bits in a physical address is 15.

(1) What is the number of virtual pages?
```

I think I have this one figured out.

Page size = `8 * 2^10 = 8192`, so the offset is `13 bits`.
Virtual page number = `20 - 13 = 7` bits
Virtual pages = `2^7` pages

```
(2) What is the number of physical pages?
```

Here's where I'm a little confused. I think I'm supposed to add in the valid, dirty, and reference bits to the physical page number (which is `2`, from `15 - 13`). However `5 * 2^7 = 640 bytes`, which seems incredibly small.

```
(3) How many bits are used in the virtual address for the page offset?
```

Answered above, it appears to be `13 bits`.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid, dirty, and reference bits are in a page table entry but are not part of the address bits.  Therefore using your results there are `2^2` or `4` physical pages.

Yes this does seem small, but realize that there is only `2^15` or `32K` bytes of physical memory.

Comment: So the number of physical pages is simply 2 to the power of the physical page number? I was under the impression that it was multiplied by the number of virtual pages.

Comment: The number of physical pages is 2 to the power of the number of physical page bits, which is 2.  Or, to put another way, it is the size of the physical memory divided by the page size.